# nspredicate substitution not working

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Hi I am trying to use substitutions but I get an error

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                     @"city $C $A or "
                     " state $C $A or "
                     " name $C $A "]; // <-- crashes here
pred = [pred predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"A":self.searchBar.text,
                                                  @"C":@"contains[c]"}];
```

This is sample code from apples documentation on the subject

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
    predicateWithFormat:@"date = $DATE"];
predicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"DATE"]];
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I simple want all the $A place holders to be replaced the same string; in this case it is self.searchBar.text

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Comment: you must read this  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can only use substitution on variables.